# 1970s or 80s movie with a drink called "squirt"

Tags: story-identification, movie

I had a short hospital appointment yesterday that necessitated a general anesthetic. When I awoke I was struck with a very strong memory of a single scene in what I am sure is an old (1970s or 1980s) sci-fi movie, and am wondering if anyone can identify it from the following recollections:

Set in a dystopian future, the scene features two grown men who are in some sort of situation (maybe a prison...). Call them A and B.

A and B knew each other previously, and while A has been in this situation for some time, B is a new arrival. A offers B a drink from some sort of dispenser that ends with a drinking straw. He calls it "squirt", with a sort of sad, fatalistic tone, as if this is the only sustenance available to them. B looks on with disinterest, and doesn't take a sip.

The scene is shot as a moderate closeup, with the head and shoulders of A and B filling the scene.

Does this sound familiar to anyone else?

Comment: Just a warning to people looking be careful when googling "squirt" especially when also searching with "drink".

Comment: As for the film is there anything that makes you think it's a Science Fiction or Fantasy film? At the moment it doesn't really seem to qualify.

Comment: FWIW [squirt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squirt_(soft_drink)) is also an actual soft drink.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - yes, apologies for not highlighting the potentially unexpected Google search results.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I mean I found an actual drink so... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squirt_(soft_drink) But I get what you mean lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I reckon it's the 1984 movie of [Supergirl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergirl_(film)), with Peter O'Toole imprisoned in the Phantom Zone and offering Supergirl a squirt when she goes there too.

Comment: Wow - not quite as I remembered it, but I'm sure you're right! Thanks.